# How to modify a texture locally?

Tags: c#, c++, texture2d

I work on a Windows 8 XAML-C++ program.
I display an image like this :

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="myImage.png"/>
</Grid>
```

When the user touches it, I want to hide the area around the touched point. I also need to know when the whole image has been hidden that way by the user. I would prefer to avoid cutting my image in plenty of squares.
With XNA (on a Windows Phone application I published before), I displayed the image using Texture2D, and I used a Color[] variable to modify it pixel by pixel :

```
Color[] pixelsTexture;
(...)
this.pixelsTexture[i] = newColor;
(...)
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(GraphicDevice, this.texture.Width, this.texture.Height);
tex.SetData(this.pixelsTexture);
this.texture = tex;
```

But here, what I need is to make the image transparent, so that the user reveals the image below step by step.
I there a simple way (I mean : without using DirectX stuff) to modify an image thay way without using XNA ?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2 :**

I see :) In this case I would just go for texture modification at runtime. You don't need DirectX since you can use GDI+ to edit images at pixel level. You would use touch point to identify the center pixel of your 'un-hiding' operation and take a bunch of pixels around it an set their `Color.a` values to 0.

**EDIT :**

So, based on your comment I think what you want is to have the user hide the whole image by clicking wherever he or she wants.

You mentioned that you don't want to cut the image into squares. Well what you can do is segment the image area into a grid. Not literally, simply calculate how the grid's cells would be positioned over the image if it was placed directly on top of it.

For instance a 256 x 256 image could be covered by a grid of say 32 x 32 invisible cells. That gives us an 8 x 8 grid.

Now that we have a grid, figuring out the extents of each cell is relatively simple. You just use an array of `Rect` structures to represent your grid cells.

When the user touches the image you can use the location of the touch to figure out which grid cell has been touched by comparing touch point with the top-left and bottom-right points of each grid cell. You do this until you get a cell whose top-left point is 'smaller' and bottom-right point is 'larger' than your touch point.

Now that you know which invisible cell has been touched all you have to do is draw your 'hiding' texture directly over the cell which is conveniently a `Rect` structure :)

It's that simple. The end result would be exactly  as if you would have cut up the texture into a bunch of tiles.

In my opinion this will be a lot faster at runtime and is simpler to implement than a texture cutter etc.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER :**

I think the texture modification approach is overkill. It will introduce unnecessary overhead for peprixel updates.

Personally I would overlay a texture of desired size and shape at the touch point. The texture can be semi transparent or opaque the choice is yours.

The end result will be exactly the same as the overlay texture will cover / hide the image at touch point. The best part is you don't need any other libraries to get this working.

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise please ? I don't quite see how you "shape at the touch point".

Comment: I meant to say you can make the texture for the overlay look however you want and then simply show it above the image.

Comment: Ok, I understood that. But how can you make it opaque locally ?

Comment: The texture is going to be made in paint or photoshop or something right? So make it however you want :)

Comment: I realize that I did not describe the need with enough details. It is when the user touches the screen that a part of the image must be hidden. And this part is unknown before run time, since no one knows where the user is going to click. Moreover, the user has to make the whole image disappear, so, in the end, he will have to touch everywhere.

Comment: I apologize, it's my fault, I didn't explain the aim of the application. It is an application for children. They will see a black & white image. Then, by touching it, they will hide this image to see the one below : a colored image. So, I really need to make the image disappear, that is, becoming transparent, not being overlayed by some black rectangle.

Comment: I modified my question to explain that "hide" means here "make transparent", not "overlay with something". I think it is possible : on the store, I saw several applications doing that and they really do not look like DirectX programs. (see GS prescolar games)

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to make a texture transparent, you need to set color to `Color.Transparent`

In my case, I had to do something similar to your case - I had an image, and I needed to draw a border right outside the sprite, leaving the original sprite visible. I achieved this by dynamically creating a `Texture2D` object that had same width + 2 and same height + 2 of the original sprite (+2 is for drawing the border right outside of the original sprite, one pixel to the left, right, top and bottom). Set the new sprite color to `Color.Transparent` and then draw the border.

In your case, its a bit simpler. You dynamically create a sprite with solid color and then, whenever user touches the sprite, set the Color to Transparent.

Code below sets the sprite to transparent (I have no access to VS right now so the code may have formatting/grammar issues). If you put this code in a function, you can flip it dynamically between transparent and not.

```
for (int i=0; i<this.pixelsTexture.Count; i++)
{
    this.pixelsTexture[i] = Color.Transparent;
}
tex.SetData(this.pixelsTexture);
```

EDIT: I noticed you are writing in C++, my code is in C#, but i think it will work though.

Comment: This is what I did when I worked in XNA (see the code in my question). But when you don't use XNA, you do not have sprites, so how do you link this.pixelsTexture with the image ?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question because you have XNA tag. I thought you were working in XNA :(